# Make iframe editable in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jsfiddle

I have another question, which i'll be asking shortly, but to ask this question i first **need to get an iframe editable in jsfiddle**. It works fine on my loacal machine, but not on jsfiddle. Im assuming this is because it uses frames?

Locally I use:

```
setTimeout('document.getElementById("kupuText").contentWindow. document.designMode="on"',10);
```

But this has no effect on jsfiddle, check it out here - http://jsfiddle.net/V7b9J/

Thanks in advance, Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're coming up against the same-origin policy.  Javascript cannot work cross-domain.  This means that it can't affect the content of an iframe if the content of that iframe is served from a different domain.

Another couple of bits of advice:

- Don't use strings for `setTimeout`. Use an anonymous function instead.
- `contentWindow` is not cross-browser.

Comment: Spot on mate, removed the source and the content is editable.

@lonesomeday wrote "Don't use strings for setTimeout. Use an anonymous function instead." Sure, i would usualy, was lazy in this example.